# Error message with a Generic ESP8266 Module

Tags: runtime-error

every time I want to upload a code to my Generic ESP8266 Module it keeps doing this

```
. Variables and constants in RAM (global, static), used 28008 / 80192 bytes (34%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ DATA     1496     initialized variables
╠══ RODATA   920      constants       
╚══ BSS      25592    zeroed variables
. Instruction RAM (IRAM_ATTR, ICACHE_RAM_ATTR), used 59143 / 65536 bytes (90%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ ICACHE   32768    reserved space for flash instruction cache
╚══ IRAM     26375    code in IRAM    
. Code in flash (default, ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR), used 231620 / 1048576 bytes (22%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╚══ IROM     231620   code in flash   

A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM7
```

I tried resetting my laptop and changing ports but the result is still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.arduined.eu/tag/ch340g/

win 10 driver for CH340G solved my issue.